# Reaching out to professors in a new department for US PhD admissions

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I'm applying to a brand-new PhD program at a well-known American university focused on an interdisciplinary area, and their website and application supplemental is encouraging people to reach out to professors. A few of them were just hired for this program, and the rest were drawn from other departments.

At least one prof is encouraging emails, while others have said to just mention them on the application so they see it. My PI has a connection to one of the affiliated faculty members, and said he'd introduce me at some point. As far as the other ones go, what should I do? I don't have anything to really say/ask that won't be mentioned in my application anyways, and I think it'll be easy to cross into the spam territory.

Comment: Are you looking to work with one of them, specifically? It would be good to avoid "noise" emails.

Comment: @Buffy Some of them are more connected than others to the research I've been doing/would like to do, but I think all of their main faculty (<5 of them) would be interesting to work with.